# List files installed with makepkg

Tags: arch-linux, software-installation, aur

I'm still fairly new to arch and I tried installing [lemonbar](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Lemonbar) while customizing my system. Now I've only ever installed AUR packages with `makepkg -Si` and it worked very well most of the time since all packages had a PKGBUILD file with them. However i noticed that for some packages (like lemonbar now) I couldn't call the install program in a shell afterwards. I'm assuming the reason is that the files are installed in a directory where the shell doesn't look for commands? I tried searching for the location in the PKGBUILD file but didn't find anything.

Is there a way I can find out easily where the files have been installed?

Answer (score 2):

You say you are relatively new to Arch, thus I guess that what you are actually wanting is `makepkg -si`. The (capital) `-S` option creates a source-only tarball that is not ready to install.

`makepkg` does not install anything by itself. Rather, it builds a package and then, if the `-i` option is specified, it calls `pacman -U package_file`. The `-s` option instructs `pacman` to resolve dependencies and install missing packages.

If you only install packages through `pacman`, you can list installed files by invoking

```
$ pacman -Ql package_name
```

As far as I know, by default, invoking `makepkg` with the aforementioned options does not install anything, it just creates a tarball in the directory it is invoked from.

Comment: I see, i will read into makepkg and its flags s bit more. Does this  list installed files from AUR packages as well?

Comment: @ClaudioBrasser Yes, it does. The AUR gives you what is needed to make a package, `makepkg` makes the package and `pacman` installs it on your system, so that files that come from the AUR are listed in pacman's database too.

Answer (score 1):

By default, pacman, and `makepkg` install files in `/usr/bin`. You can print a list of all files owned by a packages with `pacman -Ql $package`.

From `man pacman`:

> -l, --list
>              List all files owned by a given package. Multiple packages can be specified on the command line.

For example:

```
pacman -Ql xterm | awk '/\/usr\/bin\// {print $NF}'                                                                                                       
/usr/bin/                                                                                                                                                     
/usr/bin/koi8rxterm
/usr/bin/resize
/usr/bin/uxterm
/usr/bin/xterm
```

But as [fra-san](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/475822/6761) points out, you haven't actually installed anything, you have just built an installable package and must now `pacman -U $package.tar.xz`.